# Linear operator's (of rank $r$) representation as a sum of $r$ linear operators

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I prove that a linear operator of rank $r$ is representable as a sum of $r$ linear operators of rank $1$, but can not be represented as the sum of a smaller number of such operators?

Comment: Are you working in an infinite dim Banach space?

Comment: I work in n-dimensional Euclidean space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An abstract answer is the following:
Let $T$ be of rank $r$ and let $\{v_1,...,v_r\}$ be a basis
for the image. Then for each $x$ we have
$Tx = \sum_{i=1}^r v_i c_i(x) $
where at first the $c_i$'s are just unknown functions of $x$
but which you then show (use linearity of $T$ and independence of the $v_i$'s) are linear functionals of $x$. So you have in fact
  $$ T x = \sum_{i=1}^r v_i c_i^T x$$
(all in terms of column vectors and their transpose) so $T$ is a sum of $r$ rank 1 operators. Conversely, if $T$ has this form then its image is in the span of the $v_i$'s so can have rank at most $r$.